# Adding more parameters to Javascript event functions

Tags: javascript, events

How do I add extra parameters to a javascript event function? I want my current event functions to take in more parameters than just an event.

My current code is:

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width,
        y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * canvas.height
    };
}

function give_mouse_coord(e) {
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    
    var pos_x = pos.x
    var pos_y = pos.y
 }

window.addEventListener('click', give_mouse_coord, false);
```

but I want to have the give_mouse_coord take in other parameters as well, for example:

```
function give_mouse_coord(e, scalar) {
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    
    var pos_x = pos.x * scalar
    var pos_y = pos.y * scalar
 }
```

I want the `window.addEventListener` to run my functions but when I try adding more parameters the function won't run.

Comment: You don't have to pass the name of a function to `addEventListener`. You can pass an anonymous function instead that does whatever, including calling other functions. What I'm saying is that you cannot change the fact that the JS engine only passes the event to the handler function but that doesn't mean you can't just do arbitrary stuff yourself, at any point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your handler function in an ad-hoc arrow func:

```
window.addEventListener('click', e => give_mouse_coord(e, whatever), false);
```

Comment: I thought there's going to be a bunch of duplicates for sure but looking for them I found lots of really bad (and accepted) answers to this very same question. Couldn't find a dupe presenting this simple and obvious solution so I gave up :/